# Windbg Crash Dump Stack Trace Keeps Every Over Function

Tags: windbg

So I have a crash dump, and using WinDbg, I am able to get the stack trace.  However, it appears to be skipping every other function.  For instance if the actual code is:

```
void a()
{
  b();
}
void b()
{
  c();
}
void c(){}
```

The stack trace would have a, and c in the stack frame and not b.  Is this expected behavior, and is there something I can do to see the entire stack trace?  I have using the command "kn" to view the stack trace.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windbg but with the compiler removing the function due to optimization. Windbg can't show what's not there. If you add a writeln to `b` you will see it appear in the stacktrace.

Comment: Okay, I thought that might be the case.  I was just hoping to view the local variables there.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler may optimize the code. One optimization is to inline methods so that `call` and `ret` statements and everything related (`push`, `pop` etc.) are removed.

For demonstration purposes, I have added a `std::cout` statement to your code which we can identify so that the full code now reads

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void c()
{
    std::cout <<  "Hello world";
}

void b()
{
    c();
}

void a()
{
    b();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

### Walkthrough in debug build

In a typical debug build, there are no optimizations and you can see the methods. To follow the example, start WinDbg first and run the executable via *File/Open executable...*.

```
0:000> .symfix e:\debug\symbols

0:000> lm
start    end        module name
010d0000 010f3000   OptimizedInlined   (deferred)             
...

0:000> ld OptimizedInlined
Symbols loaded for OptimizedInlined

0:000> x OptimizedInlined!c
010e50c0          OptimizedInlined!c (void)

0:000> bp OptimizedInlined!c

0:000> bl
 0 e 010e50c0     0001 (0001)  0:**** OptimizedInlined!c

 0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=cccccccc ebx=7efde000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000001 esi=00000000 edi=003ffa00
eip=010e50c0 esp=003ff930 ebp=003ffa00 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
OptimizedInlined!c:
010e50c0 55              push    ebp

0:000> u eip L18
OptimizedInlined!c [e:\...\optimizedinlined.cpp @ 8]:
010e50c0 55              push    ebp
010e50c1 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
010e50c3 81ecc0000000    sub     esp,0C0h
010e50c9 53              push    ebx
010e50ca 56              push    esi
010e50cb 57              push    edi
010e50cc 8dbd40ffffff    lea     edi,[ebp-0C0h]
010e50d2 b930000000      mov     ecx,30h
010e50d7 b8cccccccc      mov     eax,0CCCCCCCCh
010e50dc f3ab            rep stos dword ptr es:[edi]
010e50de 6854ca0e01      push    offset OptimizedInlined!`string' (010eca54)
010e50e3 a1e4000f01      mov     eax,dword ptr [OptimizedInlined!_imp_?coutstd (010f00e4)]
010e50e8 50              push    eax
010e50e9 e8c9c1ffff      call    OptimizedInlined!ILT+690(??$?6U?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAAV?$basic_ostreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (010e12b7)
010e50ee 83c408          add     esp,8
010e50f1 5f              pop     edi
010e50f2 5e              pop     esi
010e50f3 5b              pop     ebx
010e50f4 81c4c0000000    add     esp,0C0h
010e50fa 3bec            cmp     ebp,esp
010e50fc e838c2ffff      call    OptimizedInlined!ILT+820(__RTC_CheckEsp) (010e1339)
010e5101 8be5            mov     esp,ebp
010e5103 5d              pop     ebp
010e5104 c3              ret
```

### Walkthrough release build

In the release build, see how things change. The WinDbg commands are the same, but the methods `c()`, `b()` and `a()` cannot be found. The `std::cout` method call has been inlined into `wmain()`:

```
0:000> .symfix e:\debug\symbols

0:000> lm
start    end        module name
01360000 01367000   OptimizedInlined   (deferred)             
...

0:000> ld OptimizedInlined
Symbols loaded for OptimizedInlined

0:000> x OptimizedInlined!c

0:000> x OptimizedInlined!b

0:000> x OptimizedInlined!a

0:000> x OptimizedInlined!wmain
013612a0          OptimizedInlined!wmain (int, wchar_t **)

0:000> bp OptimizedInlined!wmain

0:000> bl
 0 e 013612a0     0001 (0001)  0:**** OptimizedInlined!wmain

 0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=6142f628 ebx=00000000 ecx=0087a6e8 edx=0019def8 esi=00000001 edi=00000000
eip=013612a0 esp=0042f8f8 ebp=0042f934 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
OptimizedInlined!wmain:
013612a0 8b0d44303601    mov     ecx,dword ptr [OptimizedInlined!_imp_?coutstd (01363044)] ds:002b:01363044={MSVCP120!std::cout (646c6198)}

0:000> u eip L4
OptimizedInlined!wmain [e:\...\optimizedinlined.cpp @ 23]:
013612a0 8b0d44303601    mov     ecx,dword ptr [OptimizedInlined!_imp_?coutstd (01363044)]
013612a6 e895040000      call    OptimizedInlined!std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (01361740)
013612ab 33c0            xor     eax,eax
013612ad c3              ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned by `Lieven`. this is a case where compiler is making function calls inline.

There are 2 things that i would suggest:

a. If you have control over the code and build environment. Build a non-optimized/debug version of the code. This will ensure that compiler does not inline functions on its own.

b. In WinDBG you can see the disassembly under View --> Disassembly. Here you can see that code for function `b()` is actually in lined under `a()`. 
In case you are comfortable with assembly debugging you can get the value of locals as well :)

Comment: Sure. For which one would you like me to add that ? Anything specific !